# Get a enumeration of a list with Immutable.js

Tags: immutable.js

For a list of "a","b","c" I want to iterate with its index, like the Python code. How do I do it? I hope for ES5 code.

```
for index,val in enumerate(["a","b","c"]): print index,val
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var list = Immutable.List(['a', 'b', 'c']);
list.forEach(function(value, index){console.log(value, index)});`

Just be aware that it will return the length of the list.